# Hijacking from submit to redirect page (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, forms, http-redirect

So we're using an online service to handle webinars on our site. 
I have full control of the HTML for the registration page but don't have control of the PHP file used in the registration. Currently, the registration form looks like this:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" name="regform" id="regform" action="http://www.onlinemeetingnow.com/register/notify.php" class="infusion-form" method="POST">
<div class="infusion-field">
    <label for="inf_field_FirstName">First Name *</label>
    <input class="infusion-field-input-container" id="name" name="name" type="text" value="Your First Name" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;"/>
</div>
<div class="infusion-field">
    <label for="inf_field_Email">Best Email *</label>
    <input class="infusion-field-input-container" id="email" name="email" type="text" value="Your Best Email" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;"/>
</div>
<div class="infusion-submit">
    <input type="submit" name="go" value="Sign Up for Webinar!" />
</div>
</form>
```

This submits the values from the form to "notify.php". notify.php apparently has code to force the iframe this code is hosted inside of, to redirect to another page. I don't want this to happen.

I want the form to submit, but then I want to send the user to my own ThankYou page. I'm thinking that the best way to do this is by "hijacking" the submission and sending them to the page I want.

I thought that maybe calling a custom javascript function using `onsubmit` might work. Here's what I have right now:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" name="regform" id="regform" action="http://www.onlinemeetingnow.com/register/notify.php" class="infusion-form" method="POST" onsubmit="return doRedirect();">
<div class="infusion-field">
    <label for="inf_field_FirstName">First Name *</label>
    <input class="infusion-field-input-container" id="name" name="name" type="text" value="Your First Name" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;"/>
</div>
<div class="infusion-field">
    <label for="inf_field_Email">Best Email *</label>
    <input class="infusion-field-input-container" id="email" name="email" type="text" value="Your Best Email" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;"/>
</div>
<div class="infusion-submit">
    <input type="submit" name="go" value="Sign Up for Webinar!" />
</div>
</form>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function doRedirect()
{
    window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
    return true;
}
</script>
```

For some reason it's not working though. The `iframe` continues to redirect to the page I don't want, and the window itself isn't being redirected.
Am I doing this right or is there a better way of achieving this?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Jason

UPDATE: I've confirmed that the javascript is never executing. I added: `window.alert("JAVASCRIPT EXECUTED");` and the pop-up never happens so this appears to be an issue with onSubmit rather than the javascript itself. Why won't the javascript execute in onSubmit? I tried changing it to `onSubmit="JavaScript:doRedirect();"` and that didn't work either.

Comment: You should try using AJAX.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate? Why isn't this working? Why would AJAX be better? How would I use AJAX instead?

Comment: AJAX enables you to post the form data without making the user's browser navigate to another page, so basically whatever the result of `notify.php` you can choose to ignore it completely and do your own response

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
<input type="submit" name="go" onclick="doRedirect();" value="Sign Up for Webinar!" />
```

If you are looking to completely remove the interaction with the `php` form, remove the action from the `<form>` tag

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" name="regform" id="regform" class="infusion-form" method="POST">
```

Comment: I want to keep the php interaction. (That's how the online service adds someone to the list of approved "attendees" for the webinar.) Sadly, this didn't work.

Comment: Javascript isn't executing with this either. I added the `window.alert("JAVASCRIPT EXECUTED");` and no pop-up appeared.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to try AJAX:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>

 <script>
    jQuery(function($) {
    $('#regform').submit( function(e){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            url: $(this).attr("action")
        })
                .done(function (data){
                   $(location).attr('href', 'http://stackoverflow.com');
                });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    });
</script>
  <form accept-charset="UTF-8" name="regform" id="regform" action="http://www.onlinemeetingnow.com/register/notify.php" class="infusion-form" method="POST">
    <div class="infusion-field">
    <label for="inf_field_FirstName">First Name *</label>
    <input class="infusion-field-input-container" id="name" name="name" type="text" value="Your First Name" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;"/>
    </div>
    <div class="infusion-field">
    <label for="inf_field_Email">Best Email *</label>
    <input class="infusion-field-input-container" id="email" name="email" type="text" value="Your Best Email" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;"/>
    </div>
    <div class="infusion-submit">
    <input type="submit" name="go" value="Sign Up for Webinar!" />
    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: I'm completely unfamiliar with AJAX. How would this be implemented in the current situation? Would I eliminate the `onsubmit` method of the form? Would I have to reference this somewhere?

Comment: 1.Why isn't this working?
Since as soon as you hit the submit button the page is redirected to php page. and not coming back on to the html page for executing the rest of the code and that is "window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");".

Comment: 2. Why would AJAX be better? 
Since this doesn't redirects the html page to php page, the php code is executed in the background while using ajax. and after the ajax request is successfully completed, the  code under ".done" section in the ajax function will execute.

Comment: Hmm... Well it's not redirecting to the other page anymore. Unfortunately, it's not redirecting to `http://stackoverflow.com` either.

Comment: Any way to make sure that the AJAX is actually executing?

Comment: Try adding an alert inside .done before the redirection code.

Comment: Ok, so I've confirmed that the registration is happening as expected. (The email address entered is getting the correct email.) The Alert dialog is not popping up, and no redirect is happening. Is it waiting for a response back from `notify.php`?

Comment: @JRadtheBad: Although this is not a perfect solution but as you mentioned that form is being submitted properly and still the page is not directing. What you can do is replace ".done" in the function with ".always".